# getting exception org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException

Tags: spring

Am integrating spring 4 with hibernate 4 but following exception is getting.
Any one idea?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
```

Comment: I think you are passing wrong dataSource reference in application-context xml

Comment: No am passing correct values and am able to connect same username and pwd through sql yog